# how to add horizontal line over columns at different values

Tags: highcharts

How, using highcharts, do you add a horizontal line over columns at different values. Plot-lines seem to span across all columns. We want to have a line at different levels for each column.

Please see the sample image. We are trying to add lines like those shown in red in the image.

[image]

Comment: How is the position of the line determined in each column?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894828/i-want-to-add-a-line-to-each-column-in-a-highcharts-column-chart

Answer (score 0):

[Sebastian Bockan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2021935/sebastian-bochan) is correct. This is a duplicate of [I want to add a line to each column in a Highcharts column chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894828/i-want-to-add-a-line-to-each-column-in-a-highcharts-column-chart).

It looks like the scatter chart option with a custom symbol will work.