# How to plot horizontal lines over the some columns of columnrange chart in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am working on a columnrange graph in Highcharts where I plot different measurements and confidence intervals in the same plot:
[image]

The first few columns inside a group (e.g. Januar) represent measurements for different cities, while the last column represent confidence intervals. I would like to add horizontal lines to the confidence intervals representing the data means. That is, each orange column would get its own line at a specific heigh going from the left to the right side of the orange rectangle. How do I plot such lines?

I know how to add lines as a separate series of type `line`. However, doing so, I'm not sure how to guess the exact location of orange column and also I do not know how to handle cases when some columns are hidden through the legend.

This question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894828/i-want-to-add-a-line-to-each-column-in-a-highcharts-column-chart) though I am not able to get any of that solutions to work in my case.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nikicc/rqxqm4hm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [renderer.path](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.path) to draw proper lines.

```
function drawDataMeans() {
  const intervalSeries = this.get('conf-interval'),
        series = this.series.filter(series => intervalSeries !== series)

  let lines = this.dataMeansLines

  if (!lines) {
    lines = this.dataMeansLines = series[0].data.map(series => this.renderer.path().attr({
      'stroke-width': 2,
      stroke: 'black'
    }).add(intervalSeries.group))
  }

  const visibleSeries = series.filter(series => series.visible)

  if (intervalSeries.visible && visibleSeries.length) {
    intervalSeries.data.forEach((point, i) => {
      const mean = visibleSeries.reduce((sum, series) => sum + series.data[i].high, 0) / visibleSeries.length
      const {x, width} = point.shapeArgs
      const y = this.yAxis[0].toPixels(mean, true)

      lines[i].attr({
        d: `M ${x} ${y} L ${x + width} ${y}`,
        visibility: 'visible'
      })
    })
  } else {
    lines.forEach(line => line.attr({visibility: 'hidden'}))
  }
}
```

Hook on load/redraw events

```
chart: {
  type: 'columnrange',
  inverted: false,
  events: {
    load: drawDataMeans,
    redraw: drawDataMeans
  }
},
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/dq48sq3w/