# I want to add a line from each part in column in a Highcharts stacked column chart

Tags: highcharts

Is there any way to add a single line between each serie in stacked column chart?

I found something like that ([I want to add a line to each column in a Highcharts column chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894828/i-want-to-add-a-line-to-each-column-in-a-highcharts-column-chart?lq=1)), but its not what i really looking for. Maybe someone know how can i do the same line, but for each part in stacked column chart

Comment: Could you add the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply stacking to lines as well as columns.

```
  plotOptions: {
    line: {
      stacking: 'normal',
    },
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],

  }, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1],

  }, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],

  }, {
    type: 'line',
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],

  }, {
    type: 'line',
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1],

  }, {
    type: 'line',
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],

  }]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2bq423f5/